# Создание поискового модуля аналогичного Яндекс.Услуги

Tags: php

Какой самый простой способ создания поискового модуля аналогичного по функционалу [Яндекс.Услуги - Банки](http://uslugi.yandex.ru/banki/) для сайта, созданного на платформе Parallels Plesk?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, это задача уровня, когда вопрос уже не идет о самых простых методах. Самый простой способ - самый бесполезный, фоном передавать запрос яндексу и выдирать его ответ. Но это не выход, наверняка выскакивает каптча.